# What are possible reasons ASP.NET MVC may redirect to login page second time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, response.redirect

Using forms authentication and MVC 5, I see redirect to login page occurring twice. Confirmed this with Fiddler. The sequence is this:

1. GET `testhost/myapp/`  - response redirects to URL in step 2.
2. GET `testhost/myapp/login.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fmyapp%2f` - redirects to step 3.
3. GET `testhost/myapp/login.aspx` - response status is 200 and I get the login page.

If I debug, my breakpoints are hit in global application events, such as Application_EndRequest, for every request. But the login page breakpoints are hit only on the second call that has empty query string.

I see a redirect even when I go to the login page directly (testhost/myapp/login.aspx).

And even though login page works after that I'm concerned that the query string is lost due to the second redirect.

I've disabled authorization for the login page, which made no difference:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Checked HTTP vs. HTTPS.
Any other settings to check?

**Updates:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" requireSSL="false" timeout="60" protection="All" name="SqlAuthCookie" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Redirecting code (although it only executes *after* the user logs in; in this case it takes two redirects just to get to login page):

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(sUserName, false);
```

One more thing I noticed in Fiddler is that the response for step 2 above contains ASP.NET_SessionId cookie with no value, and the response for step 3 contains that cookie with a value.

Comment: can you post your login redirection method? or the forms authentication config section?

Comment: As a workaround I ended up checking for status code 302 in Application_EndRequest event, getting necessary parameters from the request query string, and adding them back to RedirectLocation property of the Response object. This works, but it sure seems to be a problem with this particular application.